# Recursion doesn't update dictionary

Tags: python, recursion

Given a path of folders ,I have to search through all the folders and put in the dictionary as the key the extensions found in those folders.

As values I have to put the difference between the highest and the lowest depth of that extension.

For example:

(Depth from 0 always)

> A1/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/hello.txt  | Depth 8
>
> A1/d/f/hello.txt              | Depth 2
>
> So in the dictionary should be {'txt' : 6}

**SHOULD BE IMPLEMENTED USING OS LIBRARY, os.walk is not acceptable!**

What I thought to do is to make 2 dictionary , and in the first dictionary I will put as the values the MIN depth and the second dictionary I will put the MAX depth, in that way I can subtract  between 2 values of the dictionary.

```
import os, os.path

def es18(path):
    diz,diz2 = _es18(path)
    print(diz,diz2)

def _es18(path,h = 0): #h = depth =0
    diz = {}
    diz2 = {}
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        fn = path + "/" + f
        if os.path.isdir(fn):
            diz,diz2 = _es18(fn,h+1)
            diz.update(diz)
            diz2.update(diz2)
        else:
            if f[-3:] not in diz:
                diz[f[-3:]] = h
                diz2[f[-3:]] = h
            else:
                diz[f[-3]] = min(diz[f[-3]],h)
                diz2[f[-3]] = max(diz[f[-3]],h)
    diz.update(diz)
    diz2.update(diz2)
    return diz,diz2
```

The problem in my code that it returns the last extension and not all what I'v found.

Comment: `diz.update(diz)` What is the intent of this line?  Updating a dict with itself does nothing.

Comment: @JohnGordon ,I know I forgot to remove, I just tried.

Comment: `diz,diz2 = _es18(fn,h+1)` --- The `=` operator is spooky. It overwrites things.

Comment: @ImperishableNight What do you mean?, it's a recursion every time that I find a new folder I'm calling again the function +1 to the depth...
If you have a better suggestion, I'm open to listen

Comment: What you seem to want to do is `new_diz,new_diz2 = _es18(fn,h+1); diz.update(new_diz); diz2.update(new_diz2)`.

Comment: @ImperishableNight thank you for the reply :) I updated the ode now it gives me an error: 
    diz[f[-3]] = min(diz[f[-3]],h)

KeyError: 'h'

Comment: Don't you mean `diz[f[-3:]]` instead of `diz[f[-3]]`? Also tip: If you find yourself typing up an expression repeatedly, maybe it's time to give that expression a name.

Comment: @ImperishableNight What a stupid error lol, I fixed to diz[f[-3:]], but somehow, it returned identical dictionary maybe the way of the min and max values is wrong :/